# how to add typings for external js lib in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I'm using [a small library](https://github.com/darkskyapp/delaunay/blob/master/lib/delaunay.js) in my typescript (angular2) project. It simply puts "Delaunay" on the global namespace, which as a "triangulate" function. So in my code I can do:

```
let result = Delauny.triangulate(input)
```

This works fine, except that typescript complains that it doesn't know Delauny, and I haven't been able to provide a definition/declaration to fix this.

I've been looking at [the typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html), but no avail. How do I tell typescript that there is an object called Delaunay and that it has a method 'triangulate'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering this as a reference for myself, this does the trick:

```
interface Delaunay {
    triangulate(input: any): any
}
declare var Delaunay: Delaunay
```